# Duplicate tags [compile-time-constant] and [compiler-constants], should they be "constantly compiled" together?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There are two tags used for compiler constants:

- [compiler-constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-constants)
  10 questions
- [compile-time-constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compile-time-constant)
  279 questions

The languages are various, as many languages have a compile-time constants feature, which works similarly. The questions mostly seem to cover the same topic.

Seems these two tags should be merged, one becoming a synonym of the other.

Which tag makes more sense to be the synonym?

- [compiler-constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-constants)

  - Fewer questions to retag
  - Pluralized feels "meh"
  - Less obvious if it means constants *inside* the compiler or *for* the compiler?
- [compile-time-constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compile-time-constant)

  - More wordy

Comment: "compile-time-constant" is the only one that makes *sense*. No one calls them "compiler constants".

Comment: @CodyGray Does it make sense to just do that and tag this as [tag:support], or better post both as answers and have a vote?

Comment: It looks like 8 out of 10 "compiler-constants" questions are really about macros.

Comment: Yeah, there's only 10 questions, and this is subject matter where I have expertise, so there's no need for any further discussion. Your agreement, not to mention the 7 upvotes on that comment, serve as more than a sufficient sanity check. Now, whether some *additional* clean-up is needed to disambiguate questions that aren't actually about compile-time constants… that's a different question. (However, to @user2357112's point that many of the questions are about macros, yes, that's true, but they're about macros being used to define compile-time constants, so that's legit usage of the tag.)

Comment: I would take "compiler constants" to mean constants defined in the source code of the compiler itself, e.g. max source file size, error code enums, that sort of thing. But I would also guess that people using the tag on SO probably don't mean it that way. It's just not a very good or useful term.

Comment: That's the way I took it also